# Group Theory: Proof of Cauchy's Theorem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Notation:

- Let $[G:H]$ denote the index of the subgroup $H$ in $G$.
- Let $Z_G(a) = \{ x \in G : xax^{-1} = a\}$ be the centraliser of $a$ in $G$.
- Let $Z(G) = \{ x \in G: \forall z \in G (xz=zx)\}$ be the center of $G$.
- Let $[a] = \{ xax^{-1} : x \in G \}$ be the conjugacy class of $a$ in $G$.

Cauchy's theorem now states:

> Let $G$ be a finite group and $p$ a prime that divides $|G|$. Then there exists a element in $G$ of order $p$.

The proof I was given uses the fact:

- Given the $n$ distict conjugacy classes $[a_1],[a_2],...,[a_n]$ of $G$ with more than one element, then one has $$|G|= |Z(G)|+ \sum_{i=1}^{n} |[a_i]| = |Z(G)|+ \sum_{i=1}^{n} [G:Z_G(a_i)]$$

And then it argues that if $p$ divides $G$ then $p$, due to the above formula, also has to divide $Z(G)$.

Why is this so? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your result is not true. Let $G$ be a non-commutative group of order $pq$. Its center is trivial !! $p$ divides $|G|$, but $p$ doesn't divide $|Z(G)|$.

Comment: This result is true if $|G|=p^{n}$.

Comment: Yep, this appears to be in error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that this is part of an inductive proof of the theorem.

If $p\nmid|Z(G)|$, then $p\nmid[G:Z_G(a_i)]$ for some $i$. But, since $p\mid|G|$, $p\mid|Z_G(a_i)|$. Now, apply the induction hypothesis to $Z_G(a_i)$.