# Proof of $p$ divides ord$(G)$ implies there exists a $ g \in G$ such that ord$(g)=p$, confusion.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups

We let G be a finite group and p a prime. We want to show that if p ∣ ord(G) $\implies \exists g \in G : ord(g)=p$.
The proof given goes as follows:
By another theorem $\exists H \le G \exists k \in Z_{>0} : ord(H) = p^k \implies \exists h \in H : h \ne e \implies 1 < ord(h) \& ord(h) ∣ p^k \implies \exists t \in Z_{>0} : ord(h)=p^t \implies g :=h^{p^{t-1}} $ has order p.

I understand as far as we have some subgroup that does not only have the unit in it which then implies its order is greater than 1 and that ord(h) divides $p^k$ but the last implication is where I get lost, why does the statement before imply that if we define g in such a way that it then has order p, thats where I am totally lost.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group Theory: Proof of Cauchy's Theorem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2347142/group-theory-proof-of-cauchys-theorem)

Comment: Hmm not really, I just want to understand this proof and more specifically the last line, why does the h guy we define have a order p :)

Comment: Note that  $h^{p^{t-1}} \neq e$ (otherwise its order would be $\lt p^t$). The order of $h^{p^{t-1}}$ is $p$, for  $(h^{p^{t-1}})^p= h^{p^t}=e$.

Comment: If $h$ has order $p^t$ then this is saying that $h^{p^t} = e$ and there doesn't exist a $l < p^t$ such that $h^l = e$. Then by manipulating powers we have that $h^{p^t} = h^{p^{t-1}\cdot p} = (h^{p^{t-1}})^p = e$ and there cannot be an integer $m < p$ such that $(h^{p^{t-1}})^m = e$, i.e., $h^{p^{t-1}}$ has order $p$, as required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g$ has order $p$ because:
$$g^p = (h^{p^{t-1}})^p = h^{p^{t-1}\cdot p}=h^{p^t} = e \ ,$$
where the last inequality follows from the fact that the order of $h$ is $p^t$.
So, we can conclude that the order of $g$ is $\leq p$. In particular, the order divides $p$ and, since $p$ is a prime and $g\neq e$, the order must be exactly $p$.

Comment: Okey, I wasnt thinking about the fact that order of an element also meant that it raised to the order of itself will equal the unit element. Thanks!

Comment: @trompi After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark
✓
next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question.